# Antonym for "Term of Endearment"

Tags: meaning

The word/phrase I'm looking for would be an antonym for Term of Endearment. It would be a nickname given to something out of fear, rather than admiration

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [epithet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epithet)? (MW definition 1a and 1b)

> a characterizing word or phrase accompanying or occurring in place of the name of a person or thing
>
> a disparaging or abusive word or phrase

with two examples given there:

> Many were offended by her use of racial epithets.
>
> a group of angry people hurling epithets at one another

Answer (score 0):

[Pejorative](http://wikivisually.com/wiki/Terms_of_disparagement) is a term of disparagement.

> Snowflake is a pejorative for an entitled person.

Answer (score 0):

How about *terms of disparagement*?

Dictionary.com:

> [*disparagement*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disparagement): the
>   act of disparaging; something that derogates or casts in a bad light
>
> [*disparage*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disparage?s=t): to bring reproach
>   or discredit upon; lower the estimation of

*Terms of disparagement* seems to be the opposite of *terms of endearment*. The latter is positive, supports, and builds up. The latter is negative, undermines, and tears down.